# Running scala shell script : Nothing happens

Tags: scala, shell

If I run the below script (saved as jarAccessTest.sh, which is an executable file) in a command line, nothing happens:

```
#!/bin/sh
# exec scala -classpath "/usr/local/google/home/vvasuki/sanskritnlpjava/target/sanskritnlp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar " "$0" "$@"
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#

# import sanskritnlp.transliteration._;
print "hello"
```

I just see no output. Nothing. Command prompt does not return either.

What is happening here? I have to type Ctrl+C to stop whatever is happening.

EDIT: Using scala 2.9 in ubuntu 14.04 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhZv6.png

Comment: How could anyone downvote a question with "sanskritnlp" in the source text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pre-packaged version of Scala is from a long time ago and a galaxy far, far away.

You'll do better to download the latest 2.11.6 from the website.

When the `scala` runner runs a script, it starts a compile server process. If that process is borked, you may have to kill it or run `fsc -shutdown` to ask it nicely to go away.

You can try adding the `-nc` option to your script to eliminate that factor, i.e., `scala -nc` says no compile daemon.

Finally, if you're just testing your library, it's more common to run `scala -cp my.jar` and experiment from the REPL. Or if you are using SBT, start the console from there.

Anonymous suggests adding: "They seriously let you type anything on here"

To which I'll append the advice from the other answer, to run `fsc -verbose`. And note that they threaten to stop supporting `fsc` because it has issues which are maddening when they occur. For that reason, I prefer `scala -nc` for brief testing and `scalac -d script.jar script.scala` where script is an `App`.

Comment: Thank you!

Indeed, testing from a separate Ubuntu 14.04 computer which has scala 2.11.6 ( http://i.imgur.com/pwCx5UX.png ), I get appropriate error messages.

PS: I'm not testing my jar - rather, I am trying to write a script which uses classes defined in that jar. Hmm.. now if I could get the import line working ( "error: not found: object sanskritnlp" ) !

Comment: On the computer which was having the problem, the problem persisted after upgrading to 2.11.6.  `fsc -shutdown` did not return. The -nc trick worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem on the original computer was never really explained, though it is pointed out that use of the '-nc' flag worked.

The original problem might with the compilation daemon's ability to open a port. From the man page for fsc:

> The first time it is executed, the daemon is started automatically. 
>   On  subsequent  runs,  the same daemon can be reused, thus resulting in a faster compilation. The tool is especially effective when repeatedly
>   compiling with the same class paths, because the
>          compilation daemon can reuse a compiler instance.

One way to check if this is the problem is to run fsc on its own with the `verbose` flag. For example, make a script called hello.scala with

> println("Hello")

in it, and run

> fsc -verbose hello.scala

If this shows the compile server unable to connect, you've identified your problem. A first thing to try in that case would be to check that your hosts file is kosher.

(I had a similar problem, and this is what I found).

Answer (score 0):

you have a few changes to do on your code, mainly on the # line which is not a comment in scala.

```
#!/bin/sh
# exec scala -classpath   "/usr/local/google/home/vvasuki/sanskritnlpjava/target/sanskritnlp-1.0-  SNAPSHOT.jar " "$0" "$@"
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#

// import sanskritnlp.transliteration._;
print ("hello\n")
```

Comment: Removing all commented lines does not help. Same (non-)result.

PS: The code in your answer does not appear properly formatted ..